# Breaking an equation cluster that does not fit on the rest of page across two pages

Tags: equations, margins

I wonder why the compiler shift the item that does not fit the rest of the page to the next pages ?! How to tell the compiler to break such item ?!

Here is a screenshot

[image]

and here is code regarding this part

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setlength{\footskip}{15pt}

\begin{document}

XXX\\[17.5cm]
YYY
\begin{align*}
[\textbf{a},\textbf{b}]_{\mathbb{R}^9} 
= \phi\bigl([\phi^{-1}(\textbf{a}),\phi^{-1}(\textbf{b})]_{\mathfrak{u}(3)} \bigr) .
\end{align*}

We check the verification of the conditions the bracket $[\,\, , \,\,]_{\mathbb{R}^9}$ must satisfy in the following three steps:

\begin{enumerate}[nolistsep]
\item[(i)] (The $\mathbb{R}$-linearity of $[\,\, ,\,\,]_{\mathbb{R}^9}$) For arbitrary $\textbf{a},\textbf{b},\textbf{c} \in \mathbb{R}^9$ and $\alpha_1,\alpha_2 \in \mathbb{R}$, it follows by the $\mathbb{R}$-linearity of $[\,\, \,\,]_{\mathfrak{u}(3)},\phi$ and  $\phi^{-1}$ that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\bigl[\alpha_1 \textbf{a} + \alpha_2 \textbf{b} , \textbf{c}    \bigr]_{\mathbb{R}^9} 
 &= \phi\bigl( [\phi^{-1}(\alpha_1\textbf{a}+\alpha_2 \textbf{b}), \phi^{-1}(\textbf{c})]_{\mathfrak{u}(3)}  \bigr)
\\&= \phi\bigl( [\alpha_1 \phi^{-1}(\textbf{a}) + \alpha_2 \phi^{-1} (\textbf{b}), \phi^{-1}(\textbf{c}) ]_{\mathfrak{u}(3)}    \bigr)
\\&= \phi\bigl( \alpha_1 [\phi^{-1}(\textbf{a}), \phi^{-1}   (\textbf{c})]_{\mathfrak{u}(3)} + \alpha_2 [\phi^{-1}(\textbf{b}), \phi^{-1}  (\textbf{c})]_{\mathfrak{u}(3)}       \bigr)
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

latex split the block of equations normally except that when I use enumerate environment latex shifts the item entirely to the next page.. This is the only exception and I unfortunately do not know why !

Comment: Have you tried providing the instruction `\allowdisplaybreaks` in the preamble (after loading `amsmath`)?

Comment: @Mico That's an `equation*` with a `split`, don't think `\allowdisplaybreaks` would do anything. And there wouldn't be room for any of the equation anyway, you might get one more line of text on the bottom of the page before.

Comment: It does not work @Mico

Comment: In the rest of my document, latex split the block of equation normally. The only exception is when I use `\enumerate` environment. @TorbjørnT.

Comment: Does your question have anything to do with the `equation*` environment in your code? Are you not asking why the first line of the list (starting with `(The $\mathbb...`)  is moved to the second page?

Comment: as I said in the question you just deleted the example code is only useful if it demonstrates the problem. The example here doesn't show a bad page break. If it was a break Mico's answer should work but no one can test as you have provided no example, but looking at your image it is not at all clear there is space for any more text on the first page.

Comment: I provided a code, what should I do and I didn’t ?! . I deleted the previous post because it was mysterious something as you mentioned. @DavidCarlisle

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand. I can't reproduce it either. If I add `\vspace*{18.8cm}` followed by the sentence starting with `We check the verification ...` right after `\begin{document}` in your code, the first line of the list is on first page. Edit: With 18.9cm the whole list is moved to the next page because there is no space for it.

Comment: No you have not provided any useful code. You are asking about a bad page break so your code should demonstrate a bad page break, how can anyone test answers given a test case that fits on one page?

Comment: also you should say what output you expect. I can not see anything wrong with the images that you have posted (but as they are not made by the posted code they are not very helpful)

Comment: Ok, just one minute and I will provide the whole code

Comment: I provided the code starting from the equation in page 36 @DavidCarlisle

Comment: That still wont show an actual page break. Can you either \vspace or some nonsense text so that  when we compile it we can see exactly what you have in the screenshot?

Comment: I moved `\allowdisplaybreaks` before `begin{enumerate}` and it works fine and achieved what I wanted. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please look at the example _now_ I fixed it so it showed the problem.

Comment: So, basically you were ignoring a crucial part of the piece of advice given earlier, about inserting the instruction `\allowdisplaybreaks` *in the preamble*. No wonder it wasn't "working"...

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

Using `align*`and `allowdisplaybreaks` works quite normally (I simplified your code for the `enumerate` environment). `\allowdisplaybreaks` has to be used *before* the equation environment we want to break (I put it in the preamble, so all multilined equations will be broken if necessary):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}%
\usepackage{lipsum}% \usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\setlength{\footskip}{15pt}
\allowdisplaybreaks

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1-4]

\begin{enumerate}[label=(\roman*), noitemsep, topsep=2pt]
  \item (The $\mathbb{R}$-linearity of $[\,\, ,\,\,]_{\mathbb{R}⁹}$) For arbitrary $\textbf{a},\textbf{b},\textbf{c} ∈ \mathbb{R}⁹$ and $\alpha₁,\alpha₂ ∈ \mathbb{R}$, it follows by the $\mathbb{R}$-linearity of $[\,\, \,\,]_{\mathfrak{u}(3)},\phi$ and $\phi⁻¹$ that
        \begin{align*}
          \bigl[\alpha₁ \textbf{a} + \alpha₂ \textbf{b} , \textbf{c} \bigr]_{\mathbb{R}⁹}%
            & = ϕ\bigl( [\phi⁻¹(\alpha₁\textbf{a}+\alpha₂ \textbf{b}), \phi⁻¹(\textbf{c})]_{\mathfrak{u}(3)} \bigr) \\
            & = ϕ\bigl( [\alpha₁ \phi⁻¹(\textbf{a}) + \alpha₂ \phi⁻¹ (\textbf{b}), \phi⁻¹(\textbf{c}) ]_{\mathfrak{u}(3)} \bigr) \\ %
            & = ϕ\bigl( \alpha₁ [\phi⁻¹(\textbf{a}), \phi⁻¹ (\textbf{c})]_{\mathfrak{u}(3)} + \alpha₂ [\phi⁻¹(\textbf{b}), \phi⁻¹ (\textbf{c})]_{\mathfrak{u}(3)} \bigr)
        \end{align*}

  \item \lipsum[5] %
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: what does \lipsum[] stand for ?

Comment: I got this error " Missing number, treated as zero" @Mico

Comment: @HusseinEid - Why are you addressing this comment at me?

Comment: @Hussein Eid: It's a command to produce automatically fake text is some pseudo Latin language (the optional argument is the numbering of the paragraphs we want to obtain). Of course you have to use it: it's just here to produce a page break in the middle of the group of equations.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate your help @Mico

Comment: @Mico: Done, mylord!

Comment: @bernard What is the purpose of \setlength{\footskip}{15pt} in your preamble?

Comment: @pzorba75: It has nothing to do with OP's problem. It was in the question code and I didn't remove it.